# Update redux in the reactjs function, then use the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I need to open a search aid and select a value there and get it back.

When I click on the button, I open a search help, I put the data I selected into a store, but how can I use it when I come back?
I need to write the data I selected from the search help directly into an input on the front side.

```
   async showPopup(){
      const LazyLoadingComponent=await import('../../CP/SearchHelp/searchHelp');
      this.setState({lazyLoadComponent:React.createElement(LazyLoadingComponent.default)});
      await ShowPopup('http://localhost:3070/api/WorkCenter/GetWorkCenters');
      console.log(this.state.selectedRow);
      if(this.state.selectedRow!==''){
        this.setState({WorkCenterCode:this.state.selectedRow.WorkCenterCode});
      }
    }
```

Here in some way I have to wait until the page is imported.
In the **showpopup**, I actually show the data that needs to be updated by updating the redux in the search help.

```
export async function ShowPopup(apiUrl){
    var apiData=await APIGetWorkCenters(apiUrl);
    SearchHelApiData(await JSON.parse(apiData.data));
    SearchHelPopupOpen(true);
}


export const SearchHelPopupOpen=(popupOpen)=>{
    store.dispatch({
        type:'SearchHelp_popupOpen',
        popupOpen:popupOpen
    });
}

export const SearchHelApiData=(apiData)=>{
    store.dispatch({
        type:'SearchHelp_apiData',
        apiData:apiData
    });
}
```

Here I need to make my searchhelp component **async** and component until closing.
I share the codes of the searchhelp component below.

```
class SearchHelp extends BasePage {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.connect(['SearchHelp']);
    this.onSelectionChanged = this.onSelectionChanged.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    SearchHelSelectedRow('');
  }


    toggle = () => {
      SearchHelApiData('');
      SearchHelPopupOpen(false);
    }

    onSelectionChanged({ selectedRowsData }) {
      const data = selectedRowsData[0];
      SearchHelSelectedRow(data);
      SearchHelApiData('');
      SearchHelPopupOpen(false);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <MDBContainer>
          <MDBModal  size="md" isOpen={this.state.popupOpen} toggle={this.toggle} centered backdrop={false}>
            <MDBModalHeader className="" toggle={this.toggle}></MDBModalHeader>
            <MDBModalBody>
            <DataGrid
                dataSource={this.state.apiData}
                selection={{ mode: 'single' }}
                showBorders={true}
                hoverStateEnabled={true}
                keyExpr={'WorkCenterId'}
                onSelectionChanged={this.onSelectionChanged} >
              </DataGrid>
            </MDBModalBody>
          </MDBModal>
        </MDBContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm waiting for your help..

**----------EDIT-------------**

I solved my problem with the **componentDidUpdate()** method.

```
  componentDidUpdate(){
      if(this.state.selectedRow!=='' && this.state.selectedRow!==undefined){
        SearchHelSelectedRow('');
        if(this.state.selectedRow.WorkCenterId!==undefined){
        this.setState({WorkCenterCode:this.state.selectedRow.WorkCenterCode});}
        if(this.state.selectedRow.ReasonCode!==undefined){
          this.setState({ReasonCode:this.state.selectedRow.ReasonCode});}
      }
    }

    async showPopupWorkCenter(){
      await ShowPopup('http://localhost:3070/api/WorkCenter/GetWorkCenters');
    }

    async showPopupReasons(){
      await ShowPopup('http://localhost:3070/api/Reason/GetReasons');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to use Redux in your `SearchHelp` component and gain access to the Redux store, you need to connect your component to the store which I don't see you doing.

You need to three things basically to get things working, a reducer, actionCreator and a store to hold state changes. When you have these then you would have to connect your component to the store by using the `connect` higher order function which takes two arguments and wraps your component giving you access to the data stored in the store.

As an example, given your component `SearchHelp`, you can connect to the store by doing this:

```
import { connect } from 'redux'

class SearchHelp extends BasePage { ... }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   // this function has access to your redux store, so you can access the properties there
   // it should return an object
   return {
      stateProp1: state.stateProp1,
      stateProp2: state.stateProp2,
      ...
   }
}

function mapDispatchToProps() {
   // this function is not required as you could simply pass in your actions directly
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchHelp)
```

An example reducer looks like below:

```
function reducerName(state = {}, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case ACTION_TYPE:
      return { stateProp1: action.data // };
      ...

      default:
      return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: I use the basepage component to be redux connect. I use this component on every page because I use multiple store structure. this was not the question I wanted to ask. what I am trying to explain is how to use the current state in the component I want to use after updating the state in SearchHelp. My English is not very good. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Pass it as a prop